# SQL Query: How can I list out the final table like employee is filled otherwise vacant?

Tags: postgresql

Position Table:

| Id | Title | Group | Level | payScale | Totalpost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | General manager | A | l-15 | 10000 | 1 |
| 2 | Manager | B | l-14 | 9000 | 5 |
| 3 | Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | 10 |

Employee Table:

| Id | Name | Position_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | 1 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | 2 |
| 3 | Michael Brown | 2 |
| 4 | Emily Johnson | 2 |
| 5 | William Lee | 3 |
| 6 | Jessica Clark | 3 |
| 7 | Christopher Harris | 3 |
| 8 | Olivia Wilson | 3 |
| 9 | Daniel Martinez | 3 |
| 10 | Sophia Miller | 3 |

Output Table:

| Title | Group | Level | payScale | Employee_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| General manager | A | l-15 | 10000 | John Smith |
| Manager | B | l-14 | 9000 | Jane Doe |
| Manager | B | l-14 | 9000 | Michael Brown |
| Manager | B | l-14 | 9000 | Emily Johnson |
| Manager | B | l-14 | 9000 | **Vacant** |
| Manager | B | l-14 | 9000 | **Vacant** |
| Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | William Lee |
| Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | Jessica Clark |
| Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | Christopher Harris |
| Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | Olivia Wilson |
| Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | Daniel Martinez |
| Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | Sophia Miller |
| Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | **Vacant** |
| Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | **Vacant** |
| Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | **Vacant** |
| Asst. Manager | C | l-13 | 8000 | **Vacant** |

I'm expecting to output like an output table

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code:

```
WITH possition(id, title, pos_group, pos_level, pay_scale, total_post) AS (
    VALUES
    ('1', 'General manager', 'A', 'l-15', '10000', 1),
    ('2', 'Manager', 'B', 'l-14', '9000', 5),
    ('3', 'Asst. Manager', 'C', 'l-13', '8000', 10)
), employee(id, emp_name, possition_id) AS (
    VALUES
    ('1', 'John Smith', '1'),
    ('2', 'Jane Doe', '2'),
    ('3', 'Michael Brown', '2'),
    ('4', 'Emily Johnson', '2'),
    ('5', 'William Lee', '3'),
    ('6', 'Jessica Clark', '3'),
    ('7', 'Christopher Harris', '3'),
    ('8', 'Olivia Wilson', '3'),
    ('9', 'Daniel Martinez', '3'),
    ('10', 'Sophia Miller', '3')
), possition_expanded AS (
    SELECT
        generate_series(1, total_post) AS running_post,
        *
    FROM possition
), employee_possition AS (
    SELECT
        row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY possition_id) AS running_post,
        e.*
    FROM employee e
    INNER JOIN possition p ON p.id = e.possition_id
)
SELECT
    po.title,
    po.pos_group,
    po.pos_level,
    po.pay_scale,
    COALESCE(em.emp_name, 'Vacant') AS employee_name
FROM possition_expanded po
LEFT JOIN employee_possition em ON em.possition_id = po.id AND em.running_post = po.running_post
ORDER BY pos_group, COALESCE(em.emp_name, 'Vacant') = 'Vacant', employee_name
```

Explanation:
`possition` and `employee` are here for testing purposes, as stand-ins for the real tables.
`possition_expanded` selects a `total_post` number of rows per position and creates a unique position-row id.
`employee_position` assigns every employee to a position and enumerates the pairs.
The `COALESCE(em.emp_name, 'Vacant') = 'Vacant'` in the `ORDER BY` clause is a trick I got from @stefanov-sm, the point of is to leave the 'Vacant' positions at the bottom of the group.
Hope this helps.
Cheers!